# autotrain.trainers.common:wrapper:92 - No GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization

Tags: python, docker, huggingface, huggingface-hub

```py
❌ ERROR  | 2024-02-06 11:07:29 | autotrain.trainers.common:wrapper:91 - train has failed due to an exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/src/autotrain/trainers/common.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/src/autotrain/trainers/clm/__main__.py", line 186, in train
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 566, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
  File "/app/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 3032, in from_pretrained
    raise RuntimeError("No GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization.")
RuntimeError: No GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization.

❌ ERROR  | 2024-02-06 11:07:29 | autotrain.trainers.common:wrapper:92 - No GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization.
```

Hugging Face auto train local in run docker and my gpu rtx4050 but auto train you not gpu error why?